# Conditional join filtering based on row value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join

I have 2 dataframes that I need to join together. There are 2 columns that we will join by, however, these 2 columns are not ids and do not produce unique row values in the other dataframe. For example, the two dataframes will look like this:

```
Dataframe 1 
    product_no   dist   code
    040          wmn    aj
    040          wmn    lm
    040          wmn    mn

Dataframe 2
    p_no   vendor    code   product
    040    wmn       **     y
    040    wmn       *j     y
    040    wmn       mn     n
```

The query for the 2 columns would look like this:

```
df1.join(df2, $"product_no" === $"p_no" && $"dist" === $"vendor")
```

This would join all rows with each other and have duplicates. However, we want to also join by `code` For example, where code is equal to the actual code in the second dataframe. If we can't find the actual, then we check if the code ends with `j` if it does, then we join by `*j` if we don't have anything that matches, we then join by `**` the result should look like this:

```
**Outcome**
        product_no   dist   code  p_no   vendor    code   product
        040          wmn    aj    040    wmn       *j     y
        040          wmn    lm    040    wmn       **     y
        040          wmn    mn    040    wmn       mn     n
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: there will be certainly a match for each key combination.. right?

Comment: @stack0114106 If the code ends with j, and there is no *j then the fall back will be **. Yes, there will always be a match at the end with ** being the fall back

Answer (score 0):

I too had gone through the some what the similar scenario where the joining is based on a conditional flag.

```
val decision: Boolean = false
val exprs = (if (decision != true) 
                   dataFrame1.col("id").equalTo(dataFrame2.col("id"))
             else dataFrame1.col("id").equalTo(dataFrame2.col("id")) 
                   and dataFrame1.col("code").equalTo(dataFrame2.col("code")))
            )
dataFrame1.join(dataFrame2, exprs).show
```

You can see sample example [here](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.com/2018/03/conditional-join-in-spark-using.html)
You can leverage the same logic here.

Instead of the conditional flag try with the row values.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
scala> val df3 = df1.alias("t1").join(df2.alias("t2"),$"product_no" === $"p_no" && $"dist" === $"vendor").withColumn("match", when($"t1.code"===$"t2.code",lit(1)).when(regexp_extract($"t1.code",".*j",0)=!=lit("") && regexp_extract($"t2.code",".*j",0)=!=lit(""), 2).when(regexp_extract($"t1.code",".*[^j]$",0)=!=lit("") &&  regexp_extract($"t2.code","[*][*]",0)=!=lit(""), 3).otherwise(lit(0))).filter('match > 0).toDF("product_no","dist","code1","p_no","vendor","code2","product","match")
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [product_no: string, dist: string ... 6 more fields]

scala> val df4= df3.withColumn("match2", collect_set('code2) over(Window.partitionBy('product_no,'dist).orderBy('match)))
df4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [product_no: string, dist: string ... 7 more fields]

scala> df4.show
+----------+----+-----+----+------+-----+-------+-----+------------+
|product_no|dist|code1|p_no|vendor|code2|product|match|      match2|
+----------+----+-----+----+------+-----+-------+-----+------------+
|       040| wmn|   mn| 040|   wmn|   mn|      n|    1|        [mn]|
|       040| wmn|   aj| 040|   wmn|   *j|      y|    2|    [*j, mn]|
|       040| wmn|   mn| 040|   wmn|   **|      y|    3|[*j, mn, **]|
|       040| wmn|   lm| 040|   wmn|   **|      y|    3|[*j, mn, **]|
+----------+----+-----+----+------+-----+-------+-----+------------+

scala> df4.selectExpr("*"," match in (1,2) or ( not array_contains(match2,code1) ) as match3 ").where('match3).show
+----------+----+-----+----+------+-----+-------+-----+------------+------+
|product_no|dist|code1|p_no|vendor|code2|product|match|      match2|match3|
+----------+----+-----+----+------+-----+-------+-----+------------+------+
|       040| wmn|   mn| 040|   wmn|   mn|      n|    1|        [mn]|  true|
|       040| wmn|   aj| 040|   wmn|   *j|      y|    2|    [*j, mn]|  true|
|       040| wmn|   lm| 040|   wmn|   **|      y|    3|[*j, mn, **]|  true|
+----------+----+-----+----+------+-----+-------+-----+------------+------+


scala>
```